# Is there a way of specifying in a machine readable way that a csv file has a header row?

Tags: csv

I am validating some csv files using the webpage csvlint.io. Here is my csv file:

```
test1,test2
0,1
```

On the webpage, I am getting a warning about a structural problem:

> **Assumed header**
>
> As there is no machine readable way to tell if your CSV has a header row, we have assumed that your CSV has one.

The wording "...to tell if *your* CSV..." leads me to believe that there are other CSV files that do not have this issue. Otherwise I would assume the wording to be "...to tell if *a* CSV...".

However, I thought .csv files by definition contain no such metadata. Am I mistaken or is the wording of the csvlint.io warning message misleading?

Comment: How is it erroneous? It says, as you did, that there's no way to specify whether the file has a header, so it assumes it does.

Comment: The wording "...to tell if _your_ CSV..." leads me to believe that there are other CSV files that do not have this issue. Otherwise I would assume the wording to be "...to tell if _a_ CSV...", hence my q.

Comment: It's just a way of wording it. Since *your* CSV (not *any* CSV) is being analyzed there's no way to tell if *your* CSV has a header.

Comment: @underscore_d So how do you specify that a row is a header row? Is there some special character that you type if you're typing it up in a plain text editor?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte no, it's all just text

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a way! I see the CSV format was standardised as [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), as apparently is implemented by PostGreSQL, and which says (bolds mine):

> This RFC documents the format of comma separated values (CSV) files and formally registers the **"text/csv" MIME type** for CSV in accordance with RFC 2048

and

> There maybe [*sic*] an optional header line appearing as the first line of the file with the same format as normal record lines. This header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file and should contain the same number of fields as the records in the rest of the file (**the presence or absence of the header line should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this MIME type**).

and

> Optional parameters: charset, header [...] **The "header" parameter indicates the presence or absence of the header line. Valid values are "present" or "absent".** Implementors choosing not to use this parameter must make their own decisions as to whether the header line is present or absent.

I have no idea how (whether?) supported this is by extant software, but maybe it's usable, and anyway this seems like the official word!